# Excel Mass Number Checking?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with over 5k+ rows and numbers.

I want to check these 5k+ numbers to see whether they have any "problems" within them (not errors such as #DIV/0, etc, those have already been accounted for).

So for example...a problem would be having a space in front of a number, causing that number to not be added to the sum of all numbers, etc... not logical errors, but more input errors. iserror would not work in this case, as it isn't a logical error.

Is there a way to do this automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose all your numbers are in column A, starting at `A1`.

You could then in `B1` put in the formula `=Value(A1)` and drag it down.

Then, just filter column B for `#VALUE` - That will give you all the numbers from column A that aren't seen by Excel as numeric.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On testing, `Value()` does its best to convert a value to a number, ignoring initial spaces or an apostrophe. I might use `=ISNUMBER()` in preference.

If you highlight the cells, say A2 downwards, you can create a Conditional Formatting, New Rule, Use a Formula, and enter `=ISNUMBER(A2)`; choose some formatting for these cells.